# Reset client headers on 301 redirect

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http, http-status-code-301

In my ASP.Net core REST API I am trying to redirect from a given route to a corresponding Azure Blob storage file URL with a SAS signature. It looks like:

```
[HttpGet("entity/{entityId}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] int entityId)
{
       return Redirect(DataAccess.GetEntitySasUrl(entityId));
}
```

The problem is that the calls to my API are already signed with Authentication Bearer token. So when the browser redirects the 301 response to Azure Blob storage it recieves double authentication URL signature + Bearer. But for Azure it is an error  `"Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header."`

I am wondering whether there is a standard HTTP parameters that could help to tell the browser to reset Bearer header in the redirected request.

Otherwise the only solution I can see is to return the URL with 200 response and to perform the non signed call to Azure Url in the angular frontend.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot set headers in a redirect..?